# Why do these photometric observations of Betelgeuse look "quantized" in 0.1 magnitude steps?

Tags: observational-astronomy, photometry, variable-star

The most interesting question related to this [Will Kinney tweet](https://twitter.com/WKCosmo/status/1208500846834700290) would be *what's going on with Betelgeuse?* but I can't help but wonder why **much but not all** of the photometric data is clustered in increments of 0.1 magnitude.

[These stripes](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/25742/7982) were the result of posting some preliminary data where analysis had some ultimately uninteresting effect that later disappeared, but I don't think that's the case here.

---

> So I downloaded data on Betelgeuse from @AAVSO . Here's a plot of visual magnitude vs Julian date for the last 10 years. Clearly something very strange going on -- a whole lot of anomalous dimming happening very quickly, in the last few months.

[image]

Comment: [Giant star's odd behaviour fuels speculation it's about to explode](https://www.newshub.co.nz/home/world/2019/12/giant-star-s-odd-behaviour-fuels-speculation-it-s-about-to-explode.html)

Comment: I guess because the magnitudes are measured to the nearest 0.1 mag. Quite likely if these are just visual estimates.

Comment: Since there's quite a few data points that also align to multiples of .25 as well, some that align to multiples of .05, and a minority that have finer resolution, I would assume that the data is taken from multiple observers.  The most common type of observer just has a resolution at .1 mag.

Comment: @Ghedipunk I'd definitely *accept* an answer like that; if these are visual and not photometric observations that makes 100% sense. I'd originally assumed they were photometric and/or there was some processing funnybusiness [like this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/25736/7982) going on.