# Are there home-brew photometers for amateur observing of variable stars and are they widely used?

Tags: amateur-observing, photometry

Comments on [Why do these photometric observations of Betelgeuse look “quantized” in 0.1 magnitude steps?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34482/7982) suggest that these are visual estimates, mostly (but not all) to 0.1 magnitude resolution.

Are there any designs for simple photodiode-based amateur photometers for stellar brightness measurements?

Just as an illustration of the kind of thing I'm asking about, I'm imagining a pair of binoculars with a 1 mm photodiode suspended by its wires the focal plane of one eyepiece, and a Raspberry Pi recording the photocurrent (with a small amplifier) and audio simultaneously ("I'm now measuring xxx... mark!") The data would be jumpy but presumably would reach a plateau whenever the star fell on the active area of the diode.

Or is this too impractical and not backwards-compatible with existing data?

Comment: It might be easier and more accurate to take photos of the variable star and its surroundings.  Then, you could also compare the brightness of non-varying stars to calibrate your reading, so that a night of poor visibility doesn't skew your results.

Comment: @Ghedipunk sure, if it works well that would be a great example and answer. I guess you have to spread the light out over enough pixels so that the missing light in the gaps between them averages out, perhaps a small defocus... The pinhole + photodiode (or just pinhole-sized photodiode) wouldn't suffer that particular problem, but then there's the problem of nearby objects that imaging might handle better.

Comment: Or, (assuming you're not observing Polaris) use a non-tracking tripod and a long exposure.  The Earth will take care of spreading the light out across a few pixels.

Comment: @Ghedipunk bingo, that works! [slightly related](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38797/12102)

Answer (score 1):

It should be doable with a standard photographic setup, a star catalog with distances and measurements for a some standard stars and a bit of software.

With the usual "ritual" for obtaining images from the sky with a given setup, chip and temperature (obtain dark frames, flat field frames and ground noise frames for division and subtraction) one can calibrate the brightness of an area (subframe around a star) in a photography by comparing it to known stars. The capture software or one of the many post processing packages for amateur astronomy can calculate the brightness of a region, if it is not totally saturated, i would guess if it is well away from any saturation.

A more detailed description: http://www.bellatrixobservatory.org/cvaaI/17/

Edit: An add-on script for one of the amateur software packages for doing photometry: https://pixinsight.com/doc/scripts/AperturePhotometry/AperturePhotometry.html.

Comment: Oh, that's quite an interesting link!